# Can str.format(**arg) be used to check for formatting?

Tags: python, c, regex, string, string-formatting

I can format a string with `str.format(**arg)` as such:

```
>>> a, b, c = 1123,242,32364
>>> "{}_{}_{}".format(a,b,c)
'1123_242_32364'
```

But can i use it in reverse to check whether a string adheres to certain format? E.g.

```
>>> "{}_{}_{}".check_format("a_bc_def")
True
>>> a,b,c = "{}_{}_{}".deformat("a_bc_def")
>>> a
a
>>> b
bc
>>> c
def

>>> "{}_{}_{}".chcek_format("_____")
True
>>> a,b,c = "{}_{}_{}".deformat("_____")
>>> a == b == c == "_"
True

>>> "{}_{}_{}".chcek_format("_1ad_das__")
True
>>> a,b,c = "{}_{}_{}".deformat("_1ad_das__")
>>> a
_1ad
>>> b
das
>>> c
_
```

Comment: No. Use a regular expression for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [parse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) module, described as "the opposite of format()." After I installed it with [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html):

```
>>> from parse import *
>>> parse("{}_{}_{}", "a_bc_def")
<Result ('a', 'bc', 'def') {}>
>>> a,b,c  = parse("{}_{}_{}", "_1ad_das__")
>>> a
'_1ad'
>>> b
'das'
>>> c
'_'
```